# Gazebo camera plugin rendering meshes in wrong order

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Trying to load a URDF model in Gazebo, and everything looks good in the Gazebo window. The model includes a Kinect , and when I look at the camera output, it renders the (.STL) meshes in the wrong order. See images [here](https://imgur.com/a/JvlqJ).

I've tried Gazebo 4 and 5, and both the `libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so` and `libgazebo_ros_camera.so` plugins. Is this expected behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8220/gazebo-camera-plugin-rendering-meshes-in-wrong-order/) by [drwahl](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1142/drwahl/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like it was a virtual machine (VMWare Player) issue. I ran the same code on an Ubuntu computer and everything rendered properly.

---

Originally posted by [drwahl](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1142/drwahl/) with karma: 1 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0